# Disable a select button after clicking on submit button

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, select

I am trying to disable a select field once I click on Search Submit button.
But after clicking the button, it temporarily disables it and it shows enable.
Here is my jquery code :

```
$(document).ready(function () {
  $("#search").click(function() {
    $("#cha_name").attr("disabled", true);
 });
});
```

Help would be appreciated.

Comment: This has nothing to do with php. Please edit your tags.

Comment: What do you mean by `it temporarily disables` ?

Comment: Is your page refreshed(postback)?

Comment: I quickly made a JSFiddle for you: https://jsfiddle.net/t9Ld7nwa/ It actually work. So there is perhaps a postback or something else like @Adil mentioned.

Comment: If its postback then you can disable the select in php code

Comment: @Sumit means when i click on search it disables for a second than comes back to enable mode

Answer (score 0):

instead of

```
$("#cha_name").attr("disabled", true);
```

use

```
$( "#cha_name" ).prop( "disabled", true );
```

or

```
$("#cha_name").attr("disabled", "disabled");
```

Answer (score 0):

Use

```
$("#cha_name").prop("disabled", true);
```

instead of

```
$("#cha_name").attr("disabled", true);//$("#cha_name").attr("disabled", "disabled"); will work
```

Answer (score 0):

use this below code it may help you.

```
$(document).click(function() {
  $('#onClickHideButton').prop('disabled',true);
});
```